# Google Contacts API: Service Unavailable

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api

Hello Google folks monitoring the API questions.

Today our API requests to the Contacts API are being blocked with 503 Service Unavailable and this message in html suggesting to do CAPTCHA:

> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network. This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot.
>   The block will expire shortly after those requests stop.  In the meantime, solving the above CAPTCHA will let you continue to use our services.

We checked our API console and we're nowhere close to reaching our daily API request quotas. Why is this happening?

And how is a service supposed to do CAPTCHA? It's communicating using API from our servers but those messages are intended for a human using a browser.

Comment: I am going to assuming you are accessing contacts api on behalf of a number of users does this happen with all of them or just one?   Note:  this message if memory services is based upon activity of the server itself and sometimes its location.   Its also User based which means it probably has nothing to do with contacts and more to do with the user you have authenticating or the server.

Comment: Yes, connecting using OAuth2 on behalf of many users. Our sync service respects rate limiting also and pauses exponentially per user. But what I saw two days ago was that our connections on behalf of any user were being blocked. I am not sure if one user has exceeded the requests per 100s quota or what triggered the blocking but why block our IP completely?

Comment: Are you logging the 500 errors I seem to remember that if an application gets 50 in an hour for all users combined your application gets blocked for a while.

Comment: No, I did not know about this rule.

Comment: It started happening today at 9:35 PDT again. The API is blocked for all our users now. Still don't understand why Google is doing this for all users and not just for the one that may have exceeded some API limit?

Comment: The Google Contacts API started 503ing at a high rate for us as well at Nylas, on Sept 8th at 9:35AM PDT. A few minutes ago at ~11:19AM PDT, the issue resolved itself and we're back to normal. Very strange.

Comment: Yes, resolved for us too. It looks like this time around our IPs are not blocked and no html/CAPTCHA sent in response. Ok, good.